# What kind of bug or insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, freshwater-biology

One of my friends has seen this insect-like species in water in the mountainous area in Iran (near Qom).

[image]

Comment: Where (what country / region) was is found?

Comment: @Remi.b Iran. near Qom.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like some species of [tadpole shrimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notostraca). I couldn't tell you what species. There's really no other basis for identification other than these are extremely unique. As you can imagine, they're endemic to a variety of wetland environments. The take home point, however, is it's a crustacean rather than an insect.

Comment: what information can be derived when  this crustacean is seen somewhere ?

Comment: @M.H I'm not too sure. As you can see, my [best candidate for the species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triops_longicaudatus) happens to distribute over multiple continents and countries.