# What animal / insect carcass is this? (Victoria, Australia)

Tags: species-identification, zoology

[image: This shedding was found in a rainwater pool]

During a hike on a mountain in Victoria, Australia, I came across this unusual shedding in one of the small rainwater pools. The pool looks small, but was developed long enough to have several insect species thriving in it such as water fleas and others of which I'm unsure.

This was the only shedding found and no other large insects or animals were found in this pool.

Answer (score 4):

This is a tadpole shrimp. The most common species here down under is [*Triops australiensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triops_australiensis).

Here is an image of it:

[image]

<sup>Source: https://www.flickr.com/photos/euprepiosaur/23782620153</sup>

Here is some info from Western Australia Museum (I found nothing on Victoria Museum): http://museum.wa.gov.au/creature-feature-tadpole-shrimp

PS: This is **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/60432/24284) because the species here is clearly different.